# How to delete an object in array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

```
[
  Employee {
    empId: 1000,
    empName: 'John',
    empSalary: 9123,
  },
  Employee {
    empId: 1001,
    empName: 'Doe',
    empSalary: 10000,
  },
  Employee {
    empId: 1002,
    empName: 'Jason',
    empSalary: 9812,
  },
  Employee {
    empId: 1003,
    empName: 'Jamie',
    empSalary: 6661,
  }
]
```

This is my array with set of objects. I want to take a user input and delete from the array based on ID. I've tried using splice but I keep getting errors.

```
var target = prompt("Enter id to delete:");
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i].empId === target) {
        data.splice(i, 1);
        break;
    }
}
```

If someone can please help me out please do!

Comment: Since you are iterating , Instead of splice, Can you push items to new object by skipping the ID to delete.. Hence the new object will hold elements excluding the item to delete

Answer (score 4):

The id values in the array are integers. The information you add at the prompt is a string. All you have to do is [cast the string to a number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus).

```js
const data = [{"empId":1000,"empName":"John","empSalary":9123},{"empId":1001,"empName":"Doe","empSalary":10000},{"empId":1002,"empName":"Jason","empSalary":9812},{"empId":1003,"empName":"Jamie","empSalary":6661}];

var target = +prompt("Enter id to delete:");
// ----------^

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].empId === target) {
        data.splice(i, 1);
        break;
    }
}

console.log(data);
```

Alternatively, and the preferred option these days, you can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to create a new array of updated data:

```js
const data = [{"empId":1000,"empName":"John","empSalary":9123},{"empId":1001,"empName":"Doe","empSalary":10000},{"empId":1002,"empName":"Jason","empSalary":9812},{"empId":1003,"empName":"Jamie","empSalary":6661}];

var target = +prompt("Enter id to delete:");

const newData = data.filter(({ empId }) => empId !== target);

console.log(newData);
```

Comment: Thank you!! It works. I feel so stupid that it was such a tiny error, but yes this works. Filter is a better way to go about it as well!

Comment: Good luck with the footballing.

Answer (score 3):

probably the variable **target** is type **String**, but the **empId** is type **Number**. So that '1' is not equal to 1.
I think you should replace this line:

```
if(data[i].empId === target) {
```

with the following line:

```
if(data[i].empId === +target) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't find any errors, but you have to convert the prompt result to number since the returned data is of type string.

```js
let data = [{
    empId: 1000,
    empName: 'John',
    empSalary: 9123,
  },
  {
    empId: 1001,
    empName: 'Doe',
    empSalary: 10000,
  },
  {
    empId: 1002,
    empName: 'Jason',
    empSalary: 9812,
  },
  {
    empId: 1003,
    empName: 'Jamie',
    empSalary: 6661,
  }
]


var target = prompt("Enter id to delete:");
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (data[i].empId === Number(target)) {
    data.splice(i, 1);
    break;
  }
}
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Never a good idea to mutate the array you are traversing. Use newer standards like filter to have a different array and leave the original unchanged.

Also, you might have issues with the type of data. '===' does strict type checking. You can either use '==' or parse the target into a number.

```
let newData = data.filter((employee) => {
return (employee.empId != target)
});
```

newData now has your array with employee with target id removed.